# What is splistitem.listitems property

Tags: splistitem

What use of `splistitem.listitems` property?  Please let me know I might find any article for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It gets the parent collection of list item objects to which the item belongs.

Type: `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection`

An `SPListItemCollection` object that represents the collection of list items.

It is part of this **Namespace**:  `Microsoft.SharePoint`

**Assembly** required :  `Microsoft.SharePoint` (in `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`)

**Syntax** :

```
       public SPListItemCollection ListItems { get; }
```

**Ex:**

If you are accessing a list item object `currentItem`, then `currentItem.listitems` will return parent collection of `currentItem`.

```
SPListItemCollection itemCollection = currentItem.listitems;
```

In short it will be similar to `SPList.Items` in most of the cases.